# How to integrate AndroidViewClient with eclipse and how to develop tests

Tags: android, eclipse, automation, androidviewclient

Can you please help me in setting up AndroidViewclient with eclipse and please give me sample example for how to write tests which will interact with any basic application.

Sorry if I am asking basic question, But I didn't see any clear step by step procedure for this.

Thanks in advance!!

Regards
ASP

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to install Python on your PC & setup PyDev into Eclipse. There are several tutorials you can find with Google for this purpose. For example   [this.](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Python/article.html)

2) Set Environment variables as described   [here.](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/dump.py)

3) AndroidViewClient zip file comes with a number of examples you can run & edit.

If you have any specific question / problem you are welcome to ask them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing *AndroidViewClient* through `easy_install` as described [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki#using-easy_install) everything will be setup correctly and in PyDev (as mentioned before) you can just

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
```

or whatever is needed.

The only small detail you should take into account if you are writing unit tests is to remove the parameters PyDev test runner added to the command line, for example here these parameters are removed in `setUpClass`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
Copyright (C) 2013  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2014-04-24 by Culebra v5.4.4

                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os

import unittest

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient


class CulebraTests(unittest.TestCase):

    kwargs1 = None
    kwargs2 = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        # Eclipse Pydev adds 4 parameters to command line:
        if len(sys.argv) >=4:
            sys.argv = sys.argv[3:]
        cls.kwargs1 = {'verbose': True, 'ignoresecuredevice': False}
        cls.kwargs2 = {'startviewserver': False, 'forceviewserveruse': False, 'autodump': False, 'ignoreuiautomatorkilled': True}

    def setUp(self):
        self.device, self.serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit(**CulebraTests.kwargs1)
        self.vc = ViewClient(self.device, self.serialno, **CulebraTests.kwargs2)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def preconditions(self):
        return True

    def testSomething(self):
        if not self.preconditions():
            self.fail('Preconditions failed')
        self.vc.dump('-1')
        pass


    @staticmethod
    def main():
        unittest.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    CulebraTests.main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Finally I'm able to do simple operations on my Android devices. I have few more questions.

1. Is it possible to 'touch'/'tap' the icon/text of app using images instead of text or ID.
2. I am able to get Package name. But I failed to get activity. can you please tell me how to get the activity details.